# Seleniumbase not found in folder directory despite installing it

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, seleniumbase

I have been trying to install `seleniumbase` via `pip install`, even though the cmd states that it has been installed.

```
Collecting wheel>=0.41.3 (from seleniumbase)
  Using cached wheel-0.41.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=23.1.0 in c:\users\xavie\anaconda3\envs\automationscript\lib\site-packages (from seleniumbase) (23.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2023.7.22 in c:\users\xavie\anaconda3\envs\automationscript\lib\site-packages (from seleniumbase) (2023.7.22)
```

I can't seem to find the `seleniumbase` file anywhere. I tried looking for it from the `anaconda navigator` and `file explorer`, both came out empty. Any reason on why that may be the case?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD6xw.png)